# How to systematically get stored procedure (SP) parameter names and their values INSIDE the SP execution

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

As described in title, I am trying to systematically get stored procedure pararameter names and their corresponding values inside the execution of the proper stored procedure.

First point, which is taking stored procedure parameter names, is easy using table [sys].[all_parameters] and the stored procedure name. However, getting the actual values of these parameters is the difficult part, specially when you are not allowed to use table [sys].[dm_exec_input_buffer] (as a developer, I am not allowed to read this table, since it is a system administrator table).

Here is the code I have so far, which I am sure can serve you as a template:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_proc_params_demo]
(
    @number1 int,
    @string1 varchar(50),
    @calendar datetime,
    @number2 int,
    @string2 nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @ParameterNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = ( SELECT STRING_AGG([Name], ',') FROM [sys].[all_parameters] WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[get_proc_params_demo]') )
    SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @ParameterNames;

    DECLARE GetParameterValues CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM [sys].[all_parameters] WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[get_proc_params_demo]'); 
        OPEN GetParameterValues;

            DECLARE @param_values NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

            DECLARE @StoredProcedureParameter NVARCHAR(MAX)
            FETCH NEXT FROM GetParameterValues INTO @StoredProcedureParameter;

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @param_values = 'ISNULL('+@param_values+','')'+@StoredProcedureParameter+','
                EXEC(@param_values)
                FETCH NEXT FROM GetParameterValues INTO @StoredProcedureParameter; 
            END;
        CLOSE GetParameterValues; 
    DEALLOCATE GetParameterValues;

    SET @param_values = LEFT(@param_values, LEN(@param_values) - 1)

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql,@ParameterNames,@param_values;

END


EXEC [dbo].[get_proc_params_demo]
    @number1=42, 
    @string1='is the answer', 
    @calendar='2019-06-19',
    @number2=123456789,
    @string2='another string'
```

This is my approach trying to dynamically get parameter actual values inside a cursor, but it does not work, and I am clueless so far. I know it is quite rudimentary, and I am happy to hear other approaches. To be fair, I don't know if this problem is even possible to solve without system tables, but it would be great.

EDIT: This is an attempt to get a generic code that works on any stored procedure. You do not want to hardcode any parameter name. The only input you have is the stored procedure name via `OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)`

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem); why do you want/need to do this? As parameters must be strictly defined in a procedure's definition, you already know what the names of the parameters are, so why do you need to do this "dynamically"?

Comment: Because I am not getting parameter names, but parameter _passed values_, or that's at least my intention :)

Comment: `SELECT N'@Number1' AS ParameterName, @Number1 AS ParameterValue;`

Comment: sure, but what if later you do have another SP for which you don't know the parameter names and values? this is an attempt to find a generic code which you can insert inside any stored procedure

Comment: *"but what if later you do have another SP for which you don't know the parameter names"* you *have* to, you **must** name the parameters when you define the procedure. If you don't know what the name of the parameters are, you just look at the `ALTER` clause, and they are right there.

Comment: I think I am not explaining it properly... the intention is to add a piece of code at the beginning of any stored procedure. For that piece of code, the input is the stored procedure name being executed, and the output is the stored procedure parameter names and values. It is mandatory to not hardcode any stored procedure parameter name, since it has a to be a general approach for many different stored procedures

Comment: So I go back to my original comment: *"This smells like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem/); why do you want/need to do this?"*

Comment: For starters, use `@@PROCID` for the object_id: `WHERE object_id = @@PROCID`

Comment: A similar question: [In SQL Server, is there a way to determine the values of the parameters passed to an executing stored procedure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142488/in-sql-server-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-values-of-the-parameters-passed-t).